# HTML-Input Hidden -> Really hidden

Tags: html, html-input

I want to make a 'captcha' to use for my website and I use this code:

```
<form class="captcha" method="post">
<label><?php echo $captchas ?></label><br>
<input name="captcha" />
<input type="hidden" name="captcha1" value="<?php echo $captchar ?>" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

`$captchas` shows the 'captcha' with random numbers in between, `$captchar` shows the true 'captcha'

At the hidden value is still really easy to gain for a non-human, how do I make the hidden input REALLY hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No HTML code will ever be 'really hidden' from your users or from a non-human. The browser will always have full access to this code. To create something effect, you would probably want to use some sort of key-value system with a database to validate that what the user/bot inputs matches up with what you expected.

Another option would be reCAPTCHA https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: Might not be what you meant, but I just made a script that created a whole database of random character-combinations with ids linked to those, so I put the id in the hidden field, that works. Thanks ;) (btw, I can't use reCAPTCHA since my 'website' is on a local host)

Comment: Yup that is essentially what I was getting at :)